# What is preventing my Chrome profile from working with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Python to automate a number of work processes that primarily take place in an online content management system, and to access the CMS, I need to be logged into my work profile on Chrome. While I could sign in once Chromedriver is open, I would have to approve the login on my authenticator each time, somewhat defeating the purpose of automation.

I am using the following code for opening Chromedriver and attempting to load my regular Chrome profile. However, while the rest of the code works as intended, it does not load my profile and I am unsure why.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Saul\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Saul\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
driver.get("https://myaccount.google.com/")
while(True):
    pass
```

I do get the following error while running the code, but I don't believe this is affecting my issue.

> 

```
C:\Users\Saul\PycharmProjects\OnlineAutomation\main.py:12: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Saul\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not related to the error you mentioned.

For the error - '`DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object`', you have to use Service:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\\Users\\Saul\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"), options=options)
```

For the Chrome profile issue, you have to mention the profile path like below:

```
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Saul\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
```

Comment: Thank you, although I seem to be missing something. It now opens regular Chrome with my profile, but it does not navigate to the given website and provides the following error among others.


selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Comment: Before executing this code, close the chrome browser(all the chrome browser windows) and then execute.

Answer (score 0):

If your website has MFA enabled, you might be able to use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) (a Python framework), which has methods for handling MFA Login:

An example test with the **BaseCase** class. Runs with **[pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html)** or **nosetests**. ([Learn more](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/ReadMe.md))

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class TestMFALogin(BaseCase):
    def test_mfa_login(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io/realworld/login")
        self.type("#username", "demo_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_pass")
        self.enter_mfa_code("#totpcode", "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG")  # 6-digit
        self.assert_exact_text("Welcome!", "h1")
        self.assert_element("img#image1")
        self.click('a:contains("This Page")')
        self.save_screenshot_to_logs()
```

An example test with the **`sb`** `pytest` fixture. Runs with **[pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html)**.

```py
def test_mfa_login(sb):
    sb.open("https://seleniumbase.io/realworld/login")
    sb.type("#username", "demo_user")
    sb.type("#password", "secret_pass")
    sb.enter_mfa_code("#totpcode", "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG")  # 6-digit
    sb.assert_exact_text("Welcome!", "h1")
    sb.assert_element("img#image1")
    sb.click('a:contains("This Page")')
    sb.save_screenshot_to_logs()
```

An example test with the **`SB`** Context Manager. Runs with pure **`python`**.

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:  # By default, browser="chrome" if not set.
    sb.open("https://seleniumbase.github.io/realworld/login")
    sb.type("#username", "demo_user")
    sb.type("#password", "secret_pass")
    sb.enter_mfa_code("#totpcode", "GAXG2MTEOR3DMMDG")  # 6-digit
    sb.assert_text("Welcome!", "h1")
    sb.highlight("img#image1")  # A fancier assert_element() call
    sb.click('a:contains("This Page")')  # Use :contains() on any tag
    sb.click_link("Sign out")  # Link must be "a" tag. Not "button".
    sb.assert_element('a:contains("Sign in")')
    sb.assert_exact_text("You have been signed out!", "#top_message")
```

There's a SeleniumBase `pytest` command-line option, `--user-data-dir=DIR`, which you can add to set a user data directory to use. Eg:

```bash
pytest --user-data-dir=DIR
```